# 2007 fusion power stering hose keeps rupturing

Tags: ford, power-steering, fusion, hose

I have a 2007 ford fusion and the power steering hose burst off. My husband fixed it easily by getting a new clamp, but then the other one actually ruptured. He went and bought a new hose and everyting, installed it, and not even 20 minutes later, the hose burst again. This has happened to my car 4 times now. With it now being snowy where I live now, my car is sitting in the driveway so I have a little more time to try to see whats going on. I am wondering if ANYONE knows what would be causing this, and how to fix it. The only thing that he can think of it being at this point is a blockage somewhere...He does know a fair amount about mechanics, but he is not a professional. Please Help! This is my Mommy mobile and I need it to take my kid places. 
Any information would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this is the return line since you're talking about clamps. I'd suggest flaring the line the hose goes over until you can confirm why there's so much pressure build up in the system. You'd probably want to put a gauge on the return line, as well as on the pressure line and post pressures. In general the return line sees fairly low pressure hence the use of clamps.